# How to start shrinking sibling div when there is not enough space

Tags: html, css

Hi I have following HTML:

```
<div>  
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
        Child one **************************************
    </div>

     <div style="display: inline-block;width: 100px;">
         Child two
    </div>  
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cVH9G/

When I resize the browser parent divs start shrinking. As soon as there is not enough space for the fixed width child two it overflows below the child one. What I am trying to achieve is to never overflow child two and always keep it at the right corner, and when there is not enough space for child two shrink child one rather than overflowing the child two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child-one">Child one **************************************</div>
    <div class="child-two">Child two</div>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}
.child-one {
    margin-right: 110px;
}
.child-two {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid gold;
    width: 100px;
}
```

You can use absolute positioning to keep the `child-two` in place.

`table-cell` also works as shown earlier, but not well supported in IE7 or below.

Floats are not a good option since you either get one of the div's starting a second line or need to hide overflow, less attractive option in my opinion.

Fiddle: hthttp://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/pbbEP/

Comment: What is the significance of making parent with position: relative?

Comment: Good question: this sets the origin for positioning the `.child-two` element.  Absolute positioned elements are placed with respect to the first block level ancestor that is not `position: static`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to give a `min-width` for your parent div:

```
<div style="border:3px solid red;min-width: 500px;">
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cVH9G/1/)**

This will ensure that your parent div is always displayed as at least 500px minimum width and will create a horizontal scrollbar when user resize the browser narrower.

Comment: That doesn't help. Basically I just want child one to shrink and child two to always stay at right corner.

Comment: That was not my question, I need parent to shrink as much as it can or expand, I just need first child to shrink with the parent resize.

Answer (score 1):

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/cVH9G/5/ (updated with improvements)

The first child resizes with the screen width and the second child stays at the right side with always `100px` width.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
<div style="border:3px solid red; ">
    <div style="border: 1px solid gold; display: inline-block; width: 20%; float:right;">
         Child two
    </div>   
    <div style="border: 1px solid green; display:inline-block; width: 75%; word-break: break-all;">
        Child one **************************************
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try working with floats; in stead of the inline blocks. I think this is what you are after http://jsfiddle.net/cVH9G/3/

Note that I also added an `overflow:hidden` to your wrapper, to prevent it from collapsing (clearfix).

Also note that i changed the order of the children, to make child2 stay at the top right, even when the parent shrinks.

The relevant css looks like this:

```
#child1 {
    display: block;
    float: left;    
}
#child2 {
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: I need child one to start shrinking as soon as there is not enough space. Currently it will overflow belog child two.

Comment: then remove the float left from child 1