# How to make a div shrink if there is not enough space inside the flexbox for other children

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css, tsx

I have this markup:

```
<div className="wrapper w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-between my-7">
     {/*first*/}
     <div className="w-full h-full min-h-0 outline-dotted outline-green-300 outline-2 p-7 bg-black overflow-y-auto whitespace-break-spaces text-nowrap">
         {data.text}
     </div>
    {/*second*/}
    <div
        className="w-full h-16 mt-5 outline-dotted outline-green-300 outline-2 p-3 bg-black flex justify-between items-center">
        <span className="text-lg font-bold">From: <span className="bg-gray-900 p-1">01/01/2024</span></span>
        <span className="text-lg font-bold">Due: <span className="bg-gray-900 p-1">05/02/2024</span></span>
     </div>
</div>
```

It's parent:

```
    <main className="flex flex-col w-full h-full">
        <div className="flex justify-between align-middle items-center h-header w-full border-b border-gray-500">
            <span className="font-bold text-2xl">Display</span>
            <CreateEditModalCallerButton buttonClassName="flex items-center justify-center p-2 hover:bg-opacity-15 hover:bg-black" mode="CREATE">
                <Image className="mr-2 w-6 h-6" src="/assets/plus-solid.svg" alt="pic" width="16" height="16"/>
                <span className="min-md:text-sm max-md:text-base">Add</span>
            </CreateEditModalCallerButton>
        </div>
        <div className="grid grid-rows-1 grid-cols-2 w-full h-full divide-x-2 divide-gray-600 px-7">
            <div className="flex flex-col w-full h-full max-sm:col-span-2 pr-7">
                <HometaskList initialData={initialHometasks}/>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-col w-full h-full pl-7 max-sm:hidden">
                {/*Problem is located here*/}
                <HometaskInfo/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

And root layout:

```
<html lang="en">
  <body className={`${font.className} w-screen h-screen flex max-md:flex-col`}>
    <StoreProvider>
      <Nav />
      <div className="root_content w-full h-screen">
        {children}
      </div>
    </StoreProvider>
  </body>
</html>
```

There are two `div`s in a flex wrapper. First one is supposed to contain a long multiline text, so I use `overflow-y-auto` to add vertical scroll when needed. This block should take all space left after placing second `div`.

The problem is that when resizing the window, first block begins to shrink freely only after bottom edge of the window meets it's border. Also, it shrinks a little bit if it has free space between bottom border and text including it's padding.

Perhaps you can better understand my problem by watching [this GIF](https://i.imgur.com/iT6Hg3i.gif).

I tried using `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow` but neither solved this problem. I also tried doing like [in the answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955178/how-to-start-shrinking-sibling-div-when-there-is-not-enough-space), but it stops shrinking at all.

The thing I want to achieve is to make first (large) div shrink and become scrollable when there is not enough space for **other children** left inside the flexbox. How can I do this? If possible, I would like to do it with Tailwind, but using standard CSS is not a problem. I would also like to know why this is happening even though first `div` has `h-full`.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: It seems you may not have provided enough code to replicate your problem. In particular `height: 100%` needs a parent to be `100%` of, so it would be good to see the parent element that it resolves to. In [this Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/FfTNRgCHZi?size=732x566), it does not behave not look like your gif.

Comment: @Wongjn I have added all the code I have on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider applying `min-height: 0` to the `.wrapper` to override its default `min-height: min-content` so that it can shrink properly:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

  <body class="w-screen h-screen flex max-md:flex-col">
    <Nav>Nav</Nav>
    <div class="root_content w-full h-screen">
      <main class="flex flex-col w-full h-full">
        <div class="flex justify-between align-middle items-center h-header w-full border-b border-gray-500">
          <span class="font-bold text-2xl">Display</span>
          <CreateEditModalCallerButton class="flex items-center justify-center p-2 hover:bg-opacity-15 hover:bg-black" mode="CREATE">
            <img class="mr-2 w-6 h-6" src="https://picsum.photos/24/24" alt="pic" width="16" height="16" />
            <span class="min-md:text-sm max-md:text-base">Add</span>
          </CreateEditModalCallerButton>
        </div>
        <div class="grid grid-rows-1 grid-cols-2 w-full h-full divide-x-2 divide-gray-600 px-7">
          <div class="flex flex-col w-full h-full max-sm:col-span-2 pr-7">
            <HometaskList initialData="{initialHometasks}">HometaskList</HometaskList>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-col w-full h-full pl-7 max-sm:hidden">
            <div class="wrapper w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-between my-7 min-h-0">
              <div class="w-full h-full min-h-0 outline-dotted outline-green-300 outline-2 p-7 bg-black overflow-y-auto whitespace-break-spaces text-nowrap">Lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
consectetur
adipiscing
elit
Etiam
placerat
erat
finibus
convallis
imperdiet
Mauris
elementum
euismod
dolor
ut
hendrerit</div>
              <div class="w-full h-16 mt-5 outline-dotted outline-green-300 outline-2 p-3 bg-black flex justify-between items-center">
                <span class="text-lg font-bold">From: <span class="bg-gray-900 p-1">01/01/2024</span></span>
                <span class="text-lg font-bold">Due: <span class="bg-gray-900 p-1">05/02/2024</span></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```